# 2-forms on $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

I've read that the group $H^2_{dR}(S^2)=\mathbb{R}$. If I'm not wrong, this implies that one can build closed 2-forms that are not exact.
Can somebody show me an example, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\omega=x\, dy\wedge dz + y\, dz\wedge dx + z\, dx\wedge dy$$

(Baby Rudin, Ch. 10, ex 22)

$$\omega = \sin\theta\,d\theta\wedge d\phi$$
([Exterior derivative of a complicated differential form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223775/exterior-derivative-of-a-complicated-differential-form))

Or any volume form.